# Dynamic Cast Class Unconditional issue in swift

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift, dynamic-cast

In my app I have a view which contains a top bar and a table.The tableview gets populated by getting the information from a contact from your agenda.

Until now all works fine but I want after selecting a cell from the table and pressing one of the buttons on the top bar to go to another view.Unfortunately this part doesn't work at all.

Here is what I tried :

```
class myAgendaTableViewController: UITableViewController ,UINavigationControllerDelegate,ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate{
 @IBOutlet var EditButton: UIBarButtonItem!

 @IBOutlet var table: UITableView!


 var objects : NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()
 var addressBookController :ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!
 var contactsArray :NSMutableArray! =  NSMutableArray()
 //...........//
 //the method I assigned to the edit button
 @IBAction func pressedEdit(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    self.objects.insertObject(NSDate.date(), atIndex: 0)
    var indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
    var array :NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    var ContactDetailsView : ContactDetails
    ContactDetailsView = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Agenda") as ContactDetails
    var personDict = self.contactsArray.objectAtIndex(0) as NSDictionary
    //println(personDict.objectForKey("firstName") ) //the dictionary exists and all

    ContactDetailsView.contactInfo = personDict



    var ceva : myAgendaTableViewController
    ceva = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Agenda") as myAgendaTableViewController 
    //this is the line I am getting an error at for some reason 
  }
```

The error I am getting is **dynamicCastClassUnconditional**

[image]

I have done this times before and never got this kind of an error.

Can you guys please explain me what I did wrong?

Comment: Im getting the same error. Are you on Xcode6beta6?

Comment: yes,I found the fix for this.if you still have the issue let me know

Comment: What was it for you?  I had the wrong identifier for my vc.  But instead of using that method to instantiate and present, I ended up going with prepareForSegue method and just set my property for the destination controller there.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Any resolution?

Comment: @tudoricc what is the solution?

Answer (score 13):

The error means that you said `as` and lied. So:

```
ceva = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Agenda") as myAgendaTableViewController
```

So you are saying `as myAgendaTableViewController`, but this object is *not* a myAgendaTableViewController.

Comment: You are a bright man Matt, and saved me a lot of work. Thank-you sincerely.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting this issue check to make sure you have assigned the class to the viewcontroller. Go to the storyboard and select your viewcontroller, then under the identity inspector panel make sure you have assigned the proper name of your class to your viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting following error:

swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional

Swift dynamic cast failed

Problem code: I was using CredentialsSetting ViewController every time when connect to different segue

```
 // programming mark ----- ----- ---- ----- ----- ---- ----- ----- ----

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

            var detailController = segue.destinationViewController as CredentialsSetting;
            detailController.viewControllerType = self.viewControllerType


    }// end prepareForSegue
```

Solution: to solve this I have added the specific condition to transfer segue for differennt connections:

```
 // programming mark ----- ----- ---- ----- ----- ---- ----- ----- ----

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {


        if self.viewControllerType == "donothavepassword" || self.viewControllerType == "forgotpassword"  {

            var detailController = segue.destinationViewController as CredentialsSetting;
            detailController.viewControllerType = self.viewControllerType


        }


    }// end prepareForSegue
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem. There's something going wrong in prepareForSegue. Instead, I just instantiated and pushed the view controller myself:

```
 let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Identifier")
            as MyViewController
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem. Everything was proper, class set, using proper identifier.

Lastly I modified the name of Identifier, 'Storyboard ID' in storyboard. Used the modified Identifier name to

```
let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("IdentifierID")
        as MyViewController
```

It started working.

Hope this is useful to others in similar situation.